# Deadbolt 2.5.0, unable to instantiate custom SubjectPresentHandler extending AbstractDeadboltHandler

Tags: deadbolt

I am using deadbolt 2.5.0 and I have created custom SubjectPresentHandler as below:

```
public class SubjectPresentHandler extends AbstractDeadboltHandler
{
    public SubjectPresentHandler(ExecutionContextProvider ecProvider) {
        super(ecProvider);
    }
    // other required methods
}
```

And, I also have :

```
@Singleton
public class CustomDeadboltHandlerCache implements HandlerCache
{
    private final DeadboltHandler defaultHandler = new  SubjectPresentHandler();
   // other required code
}
```

Now the problem that I am facing here is I cannot instantiate SubjectPresentHandler using its default contructor. I get an error as: "The constructor SubjectPresentHandler is undefined". Now when I add default constructor in SubjectPresentHandler as below:

```
public SubjectPresentHandler() {
   super();
}
```

I get an error as: 
The constructor AbstractDeadboltHandler is undefined. If I try removing the paramaterized constructor in SubjectPresentHandler then I get error message as

```
"Implicit super constructor AbstractDeadboltHandler() is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor".
```

I am not sure how can I resolve this, thus seeking solution regarding this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor of `SubjectPresentHandler` takes an `ExecutionContextProvider` as a parameter.  The easiest way to do this is to inject one and have the creation of the handler done via Guice.

The ExecutionContextProvider is provided by `DeadboltModule` - you can see this [here](https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2-java/blob/master/code/app/be/objectify/deadbolt/java/DeadboltModule.java#L32).

```
@Singleton
public class SubjectPresentHandler extends AbstractDeadboltHandler
{
    @Inject
    public SubjectPresentHandler(ExecutionContextProvider ecProvider) {
        super(ecProvider);
    }
    // other required methods
}
```

You can also inject the handler into the handler cache:

```
@Singleton
public class CustomDeadboltHandlerCache implements HandlerCache
{
    private final DeadboltHandler defaultHandler;

    @Inject
    public CustomDeadboltHandlerCache(final DeadboltHandler defaultHandler) {
        this.defaultHandler = defaultHandler;
    }
   // other required code
}
```

If you have multiple handlers, take a look at [the documentation](https://deadbolt-java.readme.io/docs/integrating-deadbolt#injecting-handlers-into-the-handlercache) for how to handle this.

Comment: @stevechalober:  This didn't fix the issue, even if I inject SubjectPresentHandler  in CustomDeadboltHandlerCache , the compiler complain for having default contructor in SubjectPresentHandler   which is not present in our case, and as I mentioned I cannot add default contructor in SubjectPresentHandler .

Comment: Here's an example implementation: https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2-java/blob/master/test-app/app/be/objectify/deadbolt/java/test/security/MyDeadboltHandler.java

Comment: @stevechalober: Even your example doesn't have default contructor, am not sure how is that working in your case. Below are the change I did in my code, but compiler is crying for default constructor in SubjectPresentHandler. I have done changes in CustomDeadboltHandlerCache as you suggested, please see edits.

Comment: What's the exact error?  Is it something like "You must have a default constructor or a single Inject-annotated constructor"?

Comment: Could not find a suitable constructor in utils.com.comp.deadbolt.SubjectPresentHandler. Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private.
[info]   at utils.com.comp.deadbolt.SubjectPresentHandler.class(SubjectPresentHandler.java:29)
[info]   while locating utils.com.comp.deadbolt.SubjectPresentHandler
[info]     for parameter 0 at utils.com.comp.deadbolt.CustomDeadboltHandlerCache.<init>(CustomDeadboltHandlerCache.java:20)

Comment: `@Inject public SubjectPresentHandler(ExecutionContextProvider ecProvider)` fulfills this requirement.  Are you declaring your bindings in a module, e.g. https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2-java/blob/master/test-app/app/be/objectify/deadbolt/java/test/modules/CustomDeadboltHook.java ?

Comment: This time it worked, I was missing @Inject in my code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @PradeepSharma please mark the answer as correct if it helped you, it helps other people find working solutions.